# how to Show all the status(error ,info and warning messages to user in e4 RCP?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I want to show all the errors or execption to users in E4 RCP app.One way is I can craeate an event topic and on each error or exception i have to  send the message to display a dialog and log it in some log file.Is there any better way to achieve samething  if I donot want to send each time application encountered any error

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `StatusReporter` class which has various methods to log and display errors.

```java
@Inject
StatusReporter statusReporter;

// Display (and log) error
statusReporter.show(StatusReporter.ERROR, "Internal Error", exception);

// Log error
statusReporter.report(status, StatusReporter.LOG);
```